# Project not synced in android studio 22.0.1 buildversion tool ubuntu

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

i want to sync my project in build 22.0.1 but when i set my gradle file as below it taking process sync continuously

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sphere65.myapplication2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22+'
}
```

Comment: Show us the output of `gradle clean build --debug` to see where the build is getting stuck